# Wordpress Issue with Walker Class

Tags: php, wordpress

What does an Illegal offset type in isset or empty, I have never ran into this error message before? Could you explain this message to me, please?

Have also place code that learning how to do in here the reviews

```
  <?php
  if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
    wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location' => 'primary_navigation',
      'menu_class' => 'menu',
      'menu_class' => 'mobile-menu',
      'walker' => new  Walker_Nav_Primary (),
      )
    );
  endif;
  ?>

class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker {
  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) { //ul
    $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
    $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"fallback$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
  }
```

> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /Users/brandonpowell/sites/valet/wordpress-development/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php on line 140

Comment: Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key.

Comment: incomplete code can't help

Comment: http://shinraholdings.com/62/custom-nav-menu-walker-function/

Comment: http://www.ibenic.com/how-to-create-wordpress-custom-menu-walker-nav-menu-class/

Comment: Hey, @vrajesh, thank you for link me to blog post quick question so it works everything but when every I refresh looks like the class that I add disappears from submenu ul element. 

I have been looking on the blog post you link me.

Comment: @BrandonPowell you can use jquery / javascript to add class into menu. use wp_header or wp_footer action to add script tag.

Answer (score 6):

This error happen when you use `Walker` instead of `Walker_Nav_Menu` in `extends`. You should use this instead:

```
class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
```

`Walker_Nav_Menu` heritate itself of `Walker` class, and provide the proper properties / methods for your own walker class.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending Walker class. Therefore you have to define db_fields in your class, it is mandatory. You wouldn't need it if you have extended Walker_Nav_Menu 
 class. Example:

```
class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker {

// Tell Walker where to inherit it's parent and id values
    var $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 
        'id'     => 'db_id' 
    );

  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) { //ul
    $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
    $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"fallback$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
  }
```